# Accessing Javascript button elements created with a forEach function (not HTML buttons)

Tags: javascript, button, foreach

I'm trying to make a NYT connections game, which requires 16 buttons. I created them using a forEach function, but only know how to access each button when I click on it. I want to disable all 4 choices when they are correct. How do I access the 4 buttons that the user chose using the button.group value? :

```
const parentElement = document.querySelector('.game-container');
    wordButtons.forEach (function (b) {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = b.word;
        button.group = b.group;
        button.id = b.buttonId;
        button.active = false;
        parentElement.appendChild(button); 

            button.onclick = function(){
                if (button.active === false){
                    //case if you click it and choose it
                    buttonIDs.push(button.id);
                    buttonGroups.push(button.group);
                    button.active = true;
                    button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                } else {
                    //case if you un-choose it
                    button.active = false;
                    button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(241, 215, 225)";
                    // remove button id from array
                    buttonIDs.splice(buttonIDs.indexOf(button.id));
                    buttonGroups.splice(buttonGroups.indexOf(button.group),1);
                }
         
                if (buttonIDs.length === 4){
                    if (buttonGroups.every(x => x === buttonGroups[0])){
                        console.log("you matched a set!");
                        if (button.group === buttonGroups[0]){
                            button.disabled = true;
                        };
                    }
                }
                }
            })
```

Sorry if I put too much code here- it is my first time asking a question here.

I tried removing the 'if buttonIds length === 4' case out of the execution context of the onclick function, hoping to access all of the buttons that way and disable them, but if I remove it from the onclick function, the code block does not execute at all.

I could probably create the buttons individually and give them numbers, but that seems like bad form.

Comment: Would you like to validate the selected buttons when the user clicks the fourth button or when clicking a submit button (the "original" seams to have a submit button)?

Comment: clicking the fourth button is good enough for me! Thanks, I have learned a lot from your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% into the game play... In the following example I went with "check state on change".

Instead of using button elements use checkboxes. A checkbox have a state -- checked or not, and can be disabled. I use both properties to decide if all in one group is checked and after that disabling all checkboxes in a group. Checkboxes are also already grouped by the name they are given in a form.

Here, I'm just going with 2 words in one group...

```js
const words = [{
  word: 'Word1',
  group: 1
}, {
  word: 'Word2',
  group: 1
}, {
  word: 'Word3',
  group: 2
}, {
  word: 'Word4',
  group: 2
}];

words.forEach(word => {
  let label = document.createElement('label');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = `group_${word.group}`;
  input.groupid = word.group;
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  span.textContent = word.word;
  label.appendChild(input);
  label.appendChild(span);
  document.forms.game.appendChild(label);
});

document.forms.game.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let checked = [...form.elements].filter(input => input.checked && !input.disabled);
  if (checked.length == 2) {
    checkGroup(e.target.groupid);
  }
  if (checked.length > 2) {
    e.target.checked = false;
  }
});

function checkGroup(groupid) {
  let form = document.forms.game;
  let inputs = form[`group_${groupid}`];
  let checked = [...inputs].filter(input => input.checked);
  if (checked.length == 2) {
    [...inputs].forEach(input => input.disabled = true);
  }
}
```

```css
label input {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em;
  margin: .2em;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

input:checked+span {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

input:checked:disabled+span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form name="game"></form>
```